# Array value sum by key value php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I check columnar values by associative key?

I want to check data by "building_id" . Here I have 2 buildings
then I want rent data as sum with group by "tenancy_rate"

*Input array :*

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 34
        [building_id] => 786
        [tenancy_rate] => 0
        [rent_per_room] => 10000
        [management_fee_per_room] => 0
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 35
        [building_id] => 786
        [tenancy_rate] => 10
        [rent_per_room] => 11810
        [management_fee_per_room] => 5400
        [rent] => 86050
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 36
        [building_id] => 786
        [tenancy_rate] => 20
        [rent_per_room] => 11810
        [management_fee_per_room] => 5400
        [rent] => 86050
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [id] => 56
        [building_id] => 798
        [tenancy_rate] => 0
        [rent_per_room] => 10000
        [management_fee_per_room] => 5400
        [rent] => 77000
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [id] => 57
        [building_id] => 798
        [tenancy_rate] => 10
        [rent_per_room] => 11810
        [management_fee_per_room] => 5400
        [rent] => 86050
    )

[5] => Array
    (
        [id] => 58
        [building_id] => 798
        [tenancy_rate] => 20
        [rent_per_room] => 11810
        [management_fee_per_room] => 5400
        [rent] => 86050
    )

)
```

*Desired result :*

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [tenancy_rate] => 0
        [rent] => 77000
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [tenancy_rate] => 10
        [rent] => 172100
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [tenancy_rate] => 20
        [rent] => 172100
    )

)
```

For this I tried PHP code

But not getting any solution

```
$sumArray = array();

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$value) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=$value;
  }
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Comment: Do you want to group by the `building_id` and sum `tenancy_rate` and `rent` ?

Comment: What you want i.e. building_id and what's your desired result i.e. tenancy_rate conflicting your expectations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` and group by index `tenancy_rate`

```
$f = [];
foreach($a as $v){
  if(!empty($f[$v['tenancy_rate']])){
    $f[$v['tenancy_rate']]['rent'] += $v['rent'];
  }else{
    $f[$v['tenancy_rate']] = [
            'tenancy_rate' => $v['tenancy_rate'],
            'rent'         => isset($v['rent']) ? $v['rent'] : 0
        ];
  }
}
```

Working example :- https://3v4l.org/nWRGA

You can use `array_values` to re arrange the order of array

Answer (score 2):

Here is the snippet. To get the desired result you need to group by tenancy_rate and not by building id,

```
$result = [];
foreach ($arr as $val) {
    // as I see, rent for some array not there, so setting it to 0
    $val['rent'] = ($val['rent'] ?? 0);
    if (isset($result[$val['tenancy_rate']]['rent'])) {
        $result[$val['tenancy_rate']]['rent'] += $val['rent'];
    } else {
        $result[$val['tenancy_rate']] = [
            'tenancy_rate' => $val['tenancy_rate'], 'rent' => $val['rent']];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/Mm8P5)

**Output:-**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [tenancy_rate] => 0
            [rent] => 77000
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [tenancy_rate] => 10
            [rent] => 172100
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [tenancy_rate] => 20
            [rent] => 172100
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

At first you need to use calculate rent sum for each tenancy rate:

```php
$rentSums = [];
foreach ($input as $info) {
    $tenancyRate = $info['tenancy_rate'] ?? 0;
    $rent = $info['rent'] ?? 0;
    $rentSum = $rentSums[$tenancyRate] ?? 0;
    $rentSums[$tenancyRate] = $rentSum + $rent;
}
```

Then you can build the result using the data from previous step:

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($rentSums as $tenancyRate => $rentSum) {
    $result[] = [
        'tenancy_rate' => $tenancyRate,
        'rent' => $rentSum,
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a function to return the necessary values (rate and rent), and accumulating the values into the `sumArray` array, making the assumption that the results array keys are related to the tenancy_rate (this allows for insertion of further tenancy_rates).

```
$sumArray = [];

function processBuildingInfo($building)
{
    return [ $building['tenancy_rate']??0, $building['rent']??0 ];
}

foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
    list($rate, $rent) = processBuildingInfo($subArray);
    $sumArray[$rate/10] = [
        'tenancy_rate' => $rate,
        'rent' => $sumArray[$rate/10]['rent'] + $rent
    ];
}

print_r($sumArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this loop:

```
foreach ($myArray as $k=>$subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $id=>$valueArray) {
    $sumArray[$id]+=[
       'tenancy_rate' => $valueArray['tenancy_rate'],
       'rent' =>  $valueArray['rent']
    ];
  }
}
```